# How does 'so much as' develop to mean 'even'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so-much-as?q=so+much+as) that helps to internalise its meaning:

> **so much as** = [with negative] Even:

I couldn't find the etymology for this adverbial phrase? Is this the correct term?

Example from  p 42, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

> Unlike many of the essays that you will have written in
>   the past, the LNAT [a test] does not seek to test factual knowledge, **so much as** understanding
>   and the ability to develop persuasive arguments. Almost without fail, there will be
>   subtleties to the question that are not immediately obvious and that will set apart
>   those candidates with a genuine insight into the subject from those with a superficial
>   knowledge.

Comment: 'Not so/as much as' (a brass farthing) = 'not even' ... they're both negative limiting modifiers.

Comment: In this example, it means *but rather*.

Answer (score 1):

As bib observes in a comment above, the meaning of "so much as [understanding and the ability]" in the OP's example is "but rather [to understand and to be able]." Alternatively, you could read it as meaning "as much as it does [understanding and the ability]."

Instances in which *so much as* carries the meaning "even" arise in contexts like the one that Edwin Ashworth cites in a comment above: "Not so much as a brass farthing." The idiomatic sense of "even" that *so much as* has in this case is quite specific. *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) identifies it among the definitions of *even*, as follows:

> **even** *adv* ... **2** ... **d :** — used as an intensive to indicate a small or minimum amount {didn't *even* try}

This usage, though commonplace both for *even* and for *so much as*, by no means constitutes the situation in which either term is most frequently encountered. Unfortunately, the *Eleventh Collegiate* doesn't make this situation at all clear. The single definition of *so much as* that it offers is essentially identical to the one that the OP cites:

> **so much as** *adv* **:** EVEN 2d {scowls if I *so much as* look at him}

The dictionary's failure to cover other senses of *so much as* is extremely disappointing, especially since readers whose grasp of English is somewhat unsteady may conclude (as the OP did here) that the only accepted use of *so much as* in English is "as an intensive to indicate a small or minimum amount." That conclusion is both inaccurate and misleading, but it's also easy to reach on the basis of MW's skimpy coverage. Regrettably, Merriam-Webster's failure to identify other valid meanings of *so much as* unwittingly encourages misunderstanding of the phrase.